# Want to know about Sri Pavhari Baba

Tags: sri-vaishnava, saint, teaching

[Pavhari Baba](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavhari_Baba) was a famous Sri Vaishnava sect of Gajipur, contemporary of Sri Ramakrishna. He was very respected in the Eastern Part of India.

I am interested in knowing about the life and especially sayings/teachings of the saint. I have read His biography by Swami Vivekananda by the way.